# Protractor: browser.wait function, isElementPresent times out

Tags: protractor

Here is my code. For some reason it cannot detect the element present, and just times out. Site is in angular. I have tried isPresent, as well as ExpectedConditions and it times out nonetheless. For some reason, it just cannot detect the element no matter how I try to locate it. I have tried multiple elements as well. I'm open to any ideas.

```
    browser.wait(function()
    {
    return browser.isElementPresent(by.xpath('//[@id="ngdialog1"]/div[2]/div/div')).then(function(present)
    {    
        console.log('\n' + 'looking for element')
        if(present)
        {
        console.log('\n' + 'recognized dialog');
        var jccSelect = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="ghId_GameSelectBottomRow"]/div[1]'));
        jccSelect.click();

        return true;
    }
})}, 50000);
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have kept ***return*** statement in ***if(present){return true;}***, if present value is ***false*** then control will not be  return, that's why your getting timed out issue.

I have rearranged the code as below:

```
 EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
 targetElement=element(by.xpath('//[@id="ngdialog1"]/div[2]/div/div'));

 browser.wait(function(){
 return EC.visibilityOf(targetElement).call().then(function(present){    
      console.log('\n' + 'looking for element')
      if(present)
        {
         //do what would you like to do
         return true;
        }
       else{
           //do what would  you like to do
           return false;
        }
 });
}, 50000);
```

Comment: Hey, I implemented your suggestion but I still have a few problems. Neither the if nor the else seems to trigger. I am also getting a message in  the command prompt that 'A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow'.

Comment: @mysticoder i have updated code with protractor.ExpectedConditions. Can you try it once.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, and the function returned false (which is an improvement), butwas unable to locate the element. No matter what I put as the element, it can't seem to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: May be locator your using is incorrect, so let me show your html code for that elemen, i will tell you locator for it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sD5L7t29

I am tryingt to locate '<div class="c_GameSelectView">'

Comment: Here is the link to the website: https://apps.facebook.com/luckystreak/
Basically, I am trying to wait until the game select panel is open, and then I want to open a machine.

Comment: Fixed, your solution worked once I was in the right frame! I was in the wrong frame this whole time. Thanks again